# Helix Toolkit - What causes the display bug

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I load a model, give it a material, and then assign it to the Content HelixViewport3D, why the color of model is not smooth.
Image is here:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUd7d.png)

C# code is:

```
MeshGeometry3D meshGeometry3D = new MeshGeometry3D()
{
    Positions = points,
    TriangleIndices = triangleIndices
};
meshGeometry3D.Freeze();
GeometryModel3D geometry = new GeometryModel3D()
{
    Geometry = meshGeometry3D,
    Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GhostWhite)),
    BackMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange))
};
models.Children.Add(geometry);
Mv3dMain.Content = models;
```

xaml code is here:

```
<h:HelixViewport3D x:Name="Hv3dMain" ...>
    <h:DefaultLights/>
    ...
</h:HelixViewport3D>
```

Comment: Probably you didn't assign correct normal values

Comment: Yes, agree.. how did you import it? and why are the Normals *not assigned* in the first statement ?